# camp4: How to match Ast.TySum to retrieve Ast.TyOr

Tags: parsing, camlp4

I'm new with ocamlp4. I'm reading [Jake Donham's blog](http://ambassadortothecomputers.blogspot.com/2010/03/reading-camlp4-part-5-filters.html) to get started with it.

I'm trying to write a small CamlP4 program wich will get a simple type as:

```
type t = Foo | Bar | Baz
```

and generate a `t_of_string` and a `t_to_string` function.

Following the code on the [blog](http://ambassadortothecomputers.blogspot.com/2010/03/reading-camlp4-part-5-filters.html) I should be able to match the type with:

```
 let wrap_str_item si = 
    let _loc = Ast.loc_of_str_item si in 
    <:str_item< $si$ >>

match wrap_str_item si with 
  | <:str_item< type $lid:tid$ = $Ast.TySum (_, ors)$  >> ->
```

But this doesn't work. When I look at the AST with `campl4of xx.ml -printer o` and I reduce it to the interesting part:

```
(Ast.TyDcl (_, tid, [],
      (Ast.TySum (_,
        (Ast.TySum (_, ors)))), [])
```

But I need to match something like

```
(Ast.TyDcl (_loc, "t", [],
      (Ast.TySum (_loc,
        (Ast.TyOr (_loc,
              (Ast.TyOr (_loc, (Ast.TyId (_loc, (Ast.IdUid (_loc, "Foo")))),
                 (Ast.TyId (_loc, (Ast.IdUid (_loc, "Bar")))))),
              (Ast.TyId (_loc, (Ast.IdUid (_loc, "Baz")))))))),
        []))
```

It seem like the AST in the match case has a spurious `TySum`, but I wasn't able to get rid of it.

Does anyone have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a well known bug that has been fixed recently after 3.12.1 [Mantis](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5231). Beware that your solution might not work with the next version where the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution.
It's seems to be a deferente syntax in ocaml 3.12.1.
Replacing the match case by

```
 <:str_item< type $lid:tid$ = $ors$  >>
```

will succeed.

Not sure why though.